# When is iglob evaluated?

Tags: python, glob

The documentation says:

> Return an iterator which yields the same values as glob() without actually storing them all simultaneously.

Actually I don't think it is true, in particular in an environment when files are created during the execution of the program. Example:

```
import glob
g = glob.iglob("*.py")
!touch a.py
!touch z.py
next(g)
next(g)
```

The problem is that (I think) that `iglob` is evaluated when you call `next`. Is there a way to avoid it?

My problem is the following: my Python script is searching for files in a folder, recursively (`recursive=True'`) with `glob`. The point is that I have tons of files, and there is no need to store all the filenames at the same time since I am processing one by one, so I would like to use generators. The point is that what my program does is to move the files in subdirectories, so I am worried that it can be that `iglob` will find the same file two times since I have moved it.

Comment: If you don't want to see changes in the file system, you have to query all filenames before changing something. Use `glob`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't force `iglob()` to read the directory listing early, no. That's how generators work; they won't start any work until you actually iterate. As such, `glob()` and `iglob()` only return the same results *provided the filesystem doesn't change before iteration has completed*.

Mostly, `iglob()` *filters* lazily; for the simple no-path, non-recursive case, `os.listdir()` is called as soon as you start iterating, and iteration only involves filtering those names.

For recursive patterns (using `**`) or where there are patterns used in the path name, `iglob()` postpones loading the directory listing for subdirectories; the top-most directory without a pattern still is loaded immediately, so if subdirectories changed while iterating, you'll get inconsistent results too.

Don't use `iglob()` if you need to capture the state of the filesystem at a specific time. Use `glob()` in that case, and 'freeze' that state in a Python list.

Comment: if `os.listdir` is called immediately (I guess when the generator is created) why my example is finding also files that are created after the creation of the generator?

Comment: @RuggeroTurra: sorry, I interpreted your question with an incorrect premise (there were a few distractions going on at the time I read it). I rewrote my answer to address your actual question.

Comment: is there a way to do what `glob` does without storing all the filenames? For example store all the pointers, or the inodes, at the beginning and then yield the filenames one by one.

Comment: @RuggeroTurra: no, there isn't. You'd have to build Python objects one way or another, and then strings are pretty cheap in this regard.

Comment: @RuggeroTurra In order to achieve that you'd need to have a filesystem that supports multiversioning and, AFAIK, no common filesystem does that; besides this still wastes memory, just in the HD instead of RAM.